# disable prettyphoto on iphone / ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Just curious if anyone has a way of disabling prettyphoto on Iphones / Ipad? I tried this piece of code from the prettyphoto support site, but doesn't seem to work..

Code looks like this:

I added the following code in the closing of my head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkforIpad() {
    var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
    if (userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {

    //do nothing
    }
    else{ 

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
    });
    }}
</script>
```

Any ideas why it does't seem to be working? This is for a wordpress theme of mine which I want to disable prettyphoto on. When loading images on a small iphone screen they are barely visible.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you actually calling the `checkforIpad()` after the function declaration?

Answer (score 0):

On wordpress, you can declare `global $is_iphone;` and then test its value in your functions. You might be interested to have a look in your `wp-includes/vars.php file`.